# C# fastest way/technology to output lines/curves/plots?

Tags: c#, graphics

I need an efficient way to output plots of several data ranges in a windows application (WPF or WinForms). My colleague says he tried just DrawLine of standart .net and that was slow. Essentially,

I know there are direct graphics output technologies like OpenGL/DirectX, but those are fit for quick display of textures (2D/3D objects consisting of pre-defined pictures). But I don't know if any of those is good at primitives - I believe, say, OpenGL doesn't even have a kind of "LineTo". I understand why primitves are kinda useless nowadays (even UI in games is done via complex imagery) so this would be an "unstandart" use of technology, most likely.

So I'm kinda at a loss.

Comment: Lines don't really exist in 3D drawing.

Comment: GDI+ is probably just fine for you, although you may want double-buffering.

Comment: Just want to comment that there is no problem drawing primitives in OpenGL. You simply do line vertices, work perfectly fine with libraries such as SFML. That said, it's obviously a bit more work to deal with vertices instead of simple "LineTo" functions.

Comment: System.Drawing / Direct2D (SlimDX/SharpDX) are some good candidates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use Dynamic Data Display for scientific plots in WPF applications -http://dynamicdatadisplay.codeplex.com/

1. It fast.
2. It provide assync methods.
3. It has good tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You can use direct2d with winforms/wpf.  Direct2d has all the convenient geometry drawing methods, while being fairly performant.  Libraries like sharpdx/slimdx allow you do write all the directx code using C#.  I think that you are limited to vista and later versions of windows though.